# Rails passing parameters between controller methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I have 2 pages : Welcome & Details.

In the Welcome page, I'm asking the user to input their name and click on a button which takes you to details page. Creates an entry in db with the given name.

In the Details page, I'm asking for the age and gender. These details I'm updating in db against the name entered in the previous page.

Now, these are my two methods.

```
 def welcome
     @name = params[:name]
     if @fname
       then @record= Names.create({:name => @name})
     end
 end

 def details
     @human=Names.last
     @human.update_attributes({:age=> params[:age], :gender=> params[:gender]})
 end
```

Now, in the above code, instead of using Names.last, i want to use Names.find_by_id(name_id). But how do I pass the name_id value between these methods?

Comment: my suggestion is to go for `nested_forms` instead of going through this approach. http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised has a good tutorial.

Comment: Why can't you do this in one form itself? If this is really necessary then you will have to post the view code for us to see what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easier way to do this, without relying on nested form is to put the id of the new record in the params of the detail get request. When the user clicks on details they need to go the details of their record.

So the route can include the id if you want something like names/:id/details.

your controller

```
def new    
 Names.create(params)
end

def edit
    @human = Names.find(params[:id])
    #whatever else
end
```

Without ajax you are pretty limited here. I can't produce the entire view code but if you have two views one that creates the new record and another that edits its details, you will be on the right track.

A more common pattern here would new/edit instead of new/details.

so in your routes file you just do resources :names. This will create the 7 restful routes. 
Read about it here, http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources.

For your first day of rails you have the basics down, and following this pattern will help you a lot.

Comment: can you provide the snippet.

Comment: snippet for the controller, the route or the view?

Comment: snippet for all 3 possibly. I understood what you're saying. But I'm not really sure how to do this. Its kind of my first day with rails.

Comment: please green check me if you are satisfied with answer.

Comment: I think i understood most of it except - 

put the id of the new record in the params of the detail get request - How do I do this?

Comment: You have to put in the url of the request. So the link will look like names/:id/edit where the id is id of the name. Your link in .erb will look like 'names'<%= @name.id %> /edit or so

Answer (score 1):

You could use a hidden_field in the welcome view form:

```
# views/.../welcome.html.erb
<%= form_for @user, action: :details, ...%>
  ...
  <%= f.hidden_field :name_id, value: @record.id %> 
<% end %>

# users_controller.rb
def details
  @human = Names.find(params[:name_id])
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several approaches to take in solving this problem but a fairly simple approach would be to pass the auto-generated id through a session variable e.g.

```
def welcome
    @name = params[:name]
    if @name 
       @record= Names.create({:name => @name})
       session[:id] =  @record.id
    end
end

def details
    @id = session[:id]
    @human = Names.find_by_id(@id)
end
```